# Bibliography not appearing with Texmaker editor

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdf, texmaker, editors

I have troubles with bibliography using Texmaker editor on my new laptop.

I'm working with windows 10, downloaded the miktex package and installed it without errors. When I edit a .tex file with Texmaker the otput pdf does not show the bibliography, even if I did everthing correctly!

Say I work on the same paper on a different computer.. everything works fine: I write my paper, do the bibliography on a different .bib file, "call" the .bib from the .tex file, cite all I need to cite, build the .tex file (PdfLaTex+BibLaTex+PdfLaTex(x2)+view Pdf) and that's it. But on my new PC it doesn't, by doing the exact same steps. Also if I open a .tex whose pdf correctly showed the bibliography (say on another PC) then bibliography appears on my editor's pdf viewer, but goes away as soon as I build the file. No errors whatsoever. I build the file correctly, it's no about that.. since I have no problems on other computers.

Does anyone have a clue??

I checked for similar problems/question here but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Ok, I reply here because it would be too long for a comment.

The .blg file says It says:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: filename.aux
I couldn't open database file bibliography.bib.bib
---line 25 of file filename.aux
 : \bibdata{bibliography.bib
 :                                              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open style file utphys.bst.bst
---line 26 of file filename.aux
 : \bibstyle{utphys.bst
 :                     }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file filename.aux
I found no style file---while reading file filename.aux
(There were 4 error messages)
```

I'm using    `\bibliographystyle{utphys.bst}` for styling, with the file utphys.bst copied in the .tex folder.

Comment: What does the .blg file say?

Comment: @Bernard Hmm I see only files .aux, .bbl, .out, .aux, .synctex

Comment: Your call shoud be `\bibliography{bibliography}`.  note that there is no file extension! Same for ibibliographystyle (no file extension)!

Comment: @Johannes_B yes I have that too:
     `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
    \bibliographystyle{utphys.bst}`

Comment: *even if I did everthing correctly* No, you are not. It is wrong to include the file extension. But some systems are a bit forgiving and sanitize the wrong input.

Comment: Oh Thank you!! It was that! Didn't know it, It always worked on Ubuntu..